# In WPF, is there page close event or page change event?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

In our WPF application, a thread task is started when user navigates to a page. Now, when the user navigates to another page , this background task needs to be stopped. Is there a way to detect that this page is getting closed, or from where do we trigger the thread end?

Comment: Please provide an example code of how do you make navigation in your application.

Comment: Thank you @LukaszSzczygielek . We had a issue on navigation, that we were using new Page(). Now, we fixed to use proper navigate method. Your note helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `OnUnload` method:

```charp
protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnUnload(e);

    // trigger the end of the task. Ex:
    _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using navigationservice, there's a navigating event. This fires when navigation is requested but before it actually happens. Hence the content of your frame will be the original page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigating?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Having said that. Why not have one central piece of code deals with all navigation? That could own the one thread which should be run for whichever page is to be shown.

Comment: Thank you @Andy . For now, we used the unload event to handle the closure and it is working.